# Как убрать лишнею запятую ?

Tags: javascript

var arr = [,16,20,10];

Answer (score 2, accepted):

На случай, если JS ещё не версии 1.6 и не поддерживает `filter()`:

```
var arr = [,16,,20,10],
    tmp = [];
for( var i in arr) tmp.push( arr[i]);
arr = tmp.slice();
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sergiks/vuU5Y/)

См. [про «дырки» в массивах](http://www.2ality.com/2013/07/array-iteration-holes.html) (на англ.)

Answer (score 1):

[`arr.shift();`](http://es5.javascript.ru/x15.4.html#x15.4.4.9)

Comment: а если arr = [16,20,,10,]; ??

Comment: вам нужно убрать все ключи у которых нет  значения ?

   arr = arr.filter(function() { return true; });

http://stackoverflow.com/a/281393/815386